# Swift Mailer automatic sending form data

Tags: php, forms, email, e-commerce, swiftmailer

I'm trying to configure Swift Mailer to send form data to my email account
In short: I have a website, using which I am going to sell some stuff in my local city
There are 3 simple forms that appear when 'Buy' button is active
The point is to send data, filled in these forms directly to my email account, 
Being a newbie to PHP, I have tried for several days to make this simple script work, but it ended up a failure
here is the code of mail.php:

```
<?php
$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$phone=$_POST["phone"];
if (isset ($name))
{
$name = substr($name,0,30); 
if (empty($name))
{
echo "<center><b>Invalid name<p>";
echo "<a href=index.php>Come back and fill up the form properly</a>";
exit;
}
}
else
{
$name = "Invalid name";
}
if (isset ($email))
{
$email = substr($email,0,30); //Не может быть более 20 символов
if (empty($email))
{
echo "<center><b>Email Invalid!<p>";
echo "<a href=index.php>Try again</a>";
exit;
}
}
else
{
$email = "Invalid";
}
if (isset ($phone))
{
$phone = substr($phone,0,15); 
if (empty($phone))
{
echo "<center><b>Empty message!!!<p>";
echo "<a href=index.php>Try again</a>";
exit;
}
}
else
{
$phone = "invalid";
}
$i = "invalid";
if ($name == $i AND $email == $i AND $phone == $i)
{
echo "Error! No data was transferred to the script";
exit;
}
$to = "zakaz@playpad2.ru";  
$subject = "New order ";
$message = "Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::;
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.yandex.ru', 465, 'ssl')
 ->setUsername('zakaz@playpad2.ru')
 ->setPassword('jhfy;tdjtujdyj');

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

// Create a message
$message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Wonderful Subject')
  ->setFrom(array('kirabidzu@gmail.com' => 'PlayPad 2 Kids tablet order'))
  ->setTo(array('zakaz@playpad2.ru', 'zakaz@playpad2.ru' => 'A name'))
  ->setBody('Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::');

// Send the message
$numSent = $mailer->send($message);

if (!$numSent) {
  print "Can't send a message";
} 
echo "<center><b>Thank you<a href=index.php>Proceed</a> to continue...>";
exit;
?>"
```

here is a form, located on the main page:

```
<form name="form" action="mail.php" method="POST"><b>Name here </b> 
<br> <input type="text" size="70%" name="name" maxlength="45"> <br>
<b>Phone No </b> 
<br> <input type="text" size="70%" name="phone" maxlength="15"> <br>
<b>E-Mail </b> 
<br> <input type="text" size="70% " name="email" maxlength="45"> <br>
 <input type="submit"><div class="button"></div>
```

Please help!

Changed smtp server port, and a new error appears: 
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Expected response code 250 but got code "553", with message "553 5.7.1 Sender address rejected: not owned by auth user.\r\n"'
A can't understand why do I need "From" field if the message is sent from the site?? The person just fills up the form and I wnat to get an email with the data he or she filled in? What should I write in the "From" field?

UPD: Finally emails are sent!!! Just made 'From' and 'To' email addresses equal
Thanks to all of you for help

Comment: So it's not a matter of email not being delivered, but the emails are sent to the wrong address. Hopefully the person at playpad2.ru won't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a closing double quote on this line:

```
$message = "Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::;
```

Should be:

```
$message = "Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::;";
```

Also, you shouldn't have posted your mail account information. It's time to change your account's password.

Comment: I received the following error when trying to send email with your credentials: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host smtp.yandex.ru [Connection refused #61]'`. Is the host reachable for you?

Comment: I got the same error, how to check whether it is reachable or not? with ping command? Sorry for newbie qustions :)

Comment: I checked with `ping` and it is alive. I think you will have to check with your email provider why the mail server is not reachable. By the way, when you changed your port, what is the new error?

Comment: Sutandiono, emails deliver properly, but I want the form data to appear in the body of the mail document, how do I make it? How should I edit this string to make the data appear, can you help?
    ->setBody('Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::');

Comment: On this code towards the end: `->setBody('Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::');`, either change the single quotes to double quotes, as such: `->setBody("Name:$name::::::::::Email:$email::::::::::Phone No:$phone:::::::::");`, or simply use the `$message` you created before that: `->setBody($message);`. As a note, you need to use double quotes instead of single quotes to expand your variables to whatever it contains.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just changed quotes to double, and it appears to work properly. I'm starting to like PHP, I wish I knew it better

Answer (score 0):

Check this. Your using The SMTP server of smtp.yandex.ru

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.yandex.ru', 465, 'ssl')
```

And the sender address is from gmail

```
->setFrom(array('kirabidzu@gmail.com' => 'PlayPad 2 Kids tablet order'))
```

There are servers that check that the sender address correspond to a really user. And this looks like your problem. To solve the error I think that you have two options.

a) you can set the smtp of gmail:

```
$transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl');
```

b) take a really sender address of yandex.ru

I hoope that this help you.